# Azure webjob communication with a virtual machine in a cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-cloud-services

**Scenario**

I have an Azure **Webjob** that has been deployed in an Azure **website**, and a virtual machine in a **cloud service** that is hosting a MongoDB database. The azure web job needs to get access to the MongoDB collections

**Question**

**It is possible to add this azure website to the cloud service?** the reason for this is because I want to access MongoDB service which is available only in the internal LAN provided by the web service.

or maybe what's best approach for my azure website can get access to the MongoDB?.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/) :

1. you create a virtual network
2. you connect your app with your VM.

> The VNET Integration feature:
>
> - requires a Standard or Premium pricing plan
> - currently will only work with V1 or Classic VNETs
> - supports TCP and UDP
> - works with Web, Mobile and API apps
> - enables an app to connect to only 1 VNET at a time
> - enables up to 5 VNETs to be integrated with in an App Service Plan
> - allows the same VNET to be used by multiple apps in an App Service Plan
> - supports a 99.9% SLA due to a reliance on the VNET Gateway
>
> There are some things that VNET Integration does not support including:
>
> - mounting a drive
> - AD integration
> - NetBios
> - private site access